# Google Feeds API & Quora RSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-reader, google-feed-api

I'm trying to pull user answers from Quora's RSS feed, using the Google Feed API. The problem is that (even when I includeHistoricalEntries() and setNumEntries(999)) I only get 20 items in the response. There should be a few hundred items.

Is there a way to fix this?

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EXUpq/

Comment: You might try a solution other than the Google Feed API, which is now deprecated. [RSS to API](https://github.com/csm123/rsstoapi) provides an RSS proxy you can host yourself on Heroku or a similar service.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to fix this directly. Google Reader and the Google Feed API only have feed history going back to when a feed was first added to the system. Looking at [Reader's view of the feed](http://www.google.com/reader/view/feed/http://www.quora.com/Lisa-Galarneau/answers/rss), that feed was first seen by Reader on December 2, therefore those are the oldest entries.

If you pick a popular feed that Reader has tracked for a while (e.g. [the Google Blog](http://www.google.com/reader/view/feed/http://googleblog.blogspot.com/atom.xml)) you'll see that its history goes back much further.